# How to deal with callbacks having dot in the URL with built-in PHP server?

Tags: drupal-7, webserver, http-status-code-404, php-5.6

I am using Drupal site (with `.htaccess` and clean URLs which are working fine) within built-in PHP Development Server (run by: `php -S localhost:8888`) where in CMS I generate dynamically the XML file which I would like to expose, however when I am trying to open `/foo/bar.xml` the following error happens:

> The requested resource `/foo/bar.xml` was not found on this server.

After investigation, it seems PHP built-in server assumes that all files containing a dot they must be the files in the local filesystem.

Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [PHP Built-in web server docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), to handle custom requests, you need to specify a "router" script (given on the command line) which returns `FALSE`, then the requested resource is returned as-is, otherwise the script's output is returned to the browser.

#### Using a Router Script

Here is simple example which handles requests for images, then display them, otherwise if HTML files are requested, it will display "Welcome to PHP":

```
<?php
// router.php
if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    return false;    // serve the requested resource as-is.
} else { 
    echo "<p>Welcome to PHP</p>";
}
?>
```

#### Drupal 7 & 8

For Drupal 7 & 8, you can use [`.ht.router.php`](https://www.drupal.org/node/1543858) file, then run it as:

```
php -S localhost:8888 .ht.router.php
```